# Difference between ++ and +1

Tags: java, while-loop, infinite-loop, increment

When I had `startIndex++` in the last line of the while loop it caused an infinite loop, but using `startIndex +` 1, the program worked fine. I was wondering why this is so?

```
public static int numOccurrences(String src, String q) {

        int startIndex = src.indexOf(q);
        int counter = 0;

        while (startIndex != -1) {
            counter++;
            startIndex = src.indexOf(q, startIndex + 1);
        }

        return counter;
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure what the guarantees are in Java, but "startIndex++" means "increment startIndex and let the value of the expression be the new value" and in C, you would be "guilty" of modifying a storage twice without an intervening sequence point and thus cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: var++ is the same as var += 1. + is simply adding to the variable.

Answer (score 3):

Consider what happens - if `indexOf` fails, it returns `-1`. If you had a blind `startIndex++` after that, then your startIndex would become `0`, the loop would wrap around, and `0 != -1` is TRUE, continuing the loop. You'd get another `-1`, increment it to `0`, and around and around you go - search, fail, increment, loop/repeat.

Comment: Since `startIndex++` is evaluated before the assignment, `startIndex` will be set to `-1` if `indexOf` fails. Then the while condition kicks in and the loop ends.

Comment: I thought he meant: "instead of `startIndex + 1`". But I can be wrong, of course.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `startIndex++` increments the value of the variable `startIndex`, but it returns the old value of `startIndex`. After evaluating the expression which contains `startIndex++` you assign the result to `startIndex`. That means that in your case that increment is discarded and `startIndex++` and `startIndex` will have the exact same result: the same occurrence will be found each time, and you have an infinite loop.

The expression `startIndex + 1`, on the other hand, does not change the value of `startIndex`, but evaluates to the integer following the value of `startIndex`. Now the `indexOf` starts searching after the found occurrence, so you do not have an infinite loop.